# Индексы MySQL (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Подскажите как лучше использовать индексы. Есть таблицы и запросы к ним где в WHERE указывается несколько полей, и эти поля могут варьироваться. Нужно ли создавать индексы по каждому полю или нужно делать составные индексы по всем вариациям?

Comment: Одновременно используется только один индекс. Так что составные обычно практичнее. Так же обратите внимание, что индекс используется если в запросе используется первая колонка из него. Поля проверяемые на точные равенства должны быть в начале ключа индекса, проверяемые на больше/меньше позже. И помните, что каждый индекс занимает место на диске и замедляет операции вставки и обновления записей. Нужен баланс, подбирайте индексы только для очень частых запросов в БД, старайтесь унифицировать запросы что бы использовали один и тот же индекс

Comment: *Поля проверяемые на точные равенства должны быть в начале ключа индекса, проверяемые на больше/меньше позже.* Дополнительно - поля, имеющие минимальный процент соответствия (бОльшую вариабельность значений) желательно размещать в начале.

Comment: Вам не стоит накидывать индексы без явной на то причины, это может быть медленный запрос или же необходимость только уникального значения, но, чтобы это делать корректно, вам точно будет необходимо углубиться в данную тему. Без должных знаний, индексы, принесут вам только боль и проблемы с производительностью.

Comment: TBL[gender, age, company], кажется, что выборка может быть произведена по всем полям, и может показаться, что можно накинуть 3 одиночных индекса или один составной и что-то из этого точно будет более или менее работать (в примере, менее больное решение было бы 3 одиночных индекса). Но по хорошему, gender вообще нет смысла заводит как индекс, т.к. отсеите с помощью него ~50% записей, но fullscan явно отработает быстрее, т.е. в приведенном примере, оптимальным решением будет один составной иденкс на 2 столбца: age и company (в company, подразумевается, что не 1,2 или даже 100 компаний, а более).